# Put in angular not working to put an array into a JSON database

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to push an array comment in to cabin.comments array. The new comment is in the array but it is not pushing it to the database.
I am getting no errors

I am using a JSON database in the main folder.

I am really new to angular and I am lost.

This is my component file with my onSubmit my console log for cabin and for id here works

```
onSubmit() {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.cabin.comments.push(this.comment);
    this.cabinService.updatePosts(this.cabin.id, this.comment);
    console.log(this.cabin);
    console.log(id);

    this.commentForm.reset({
        author: '',
        rating: 5,
        comment: ''
    });
}
```

My cabinService my console log work for this.cabin but does not work for updatedEntries. The put is not working.

```
 updatePosts(id, newcomment) {
const comment: Comment = newcomment;
return this.http.get<Cabin>('http://localhost:3000/cabins/' + id).pipe(
  map(cabin => {


    return {
        id: cabin.id,
        name: cabin.name,
        description: cabin.description,
        priceweek:  cabin.priceweek,
        pricemonth:  cabin.pricemonth,
        featured: cabin.featured,
        comments: cabin.comments


    };


  })
).subscribe(updatedCabin => {
  updatedCabin.comments.push(comment);

  return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/cabins/' + id, updatedCabin);

});

}
```

My JSON database

```
      "cabins": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "description": "Tucked away on the hillside among lush gardens of banana & citrus trees",
          "featured": "true",
          "comments": [
            {
              "rating": 5,
              "comment": "Beautiful place!",
              "author": "John Gomez",
              "date": "2018-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
              "rating": 4,
              "comment": "Amazing!",
              "author": "Paul Villar",
              "date": "2017-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

Here is a link to a stackblitz of the complete project

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uonucb?embed=1&file=src/app/services/cabin.service.ts

Comment: The observable will not be fired until you subscribe to it, so you need to call `subscribe` on `this.cabinService.updatePosts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your service method, like so:

```
  updatePosts(id, newcomment) {
    const comment: Comment = newcomment;
    return this.http.get<Cabin>('http://localhost:3000/cabins/' + id).pipe(
      map(cabin => {


        return {
          id: cabin.id,
          name: cabin.name,
          description: cabin.description,
          priceweek: cabin.priceweek,
          pricemonth: cabin.pricemonth,
          featured: cabin.featured,
          comments: cabin.comments


        };


      }),
      flatMap((updatedCabin) => {
        updatedCabin.comments.push(comment);
        return this.http.put(this.cabinsUrl + '/' + id, updatedCabin);
      })
    );

  }
```

This will then chain the observables, and allow the second one to be returned. You will then be able to call subscribe like so:

```
this.cabinService.updatePosts(this.cabin.id, this.comment).subscribe(() => {
    console.log("PUT is done");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a forward-slash on this line:

```
return this.http.put('http://localhost:3000/cabins' +id, updatedEntries);
```

So you are making a PUT request to `http://localhost:3000/cabins1234` instead of `http://localhost:3000/cabins/1234`, and the former endpoint does not exist.

Comment: I added the forward-slash and it still doesn't add it to the database.

Comment: @user3149979 As I mention above, the HTTP call will never be made unless you `subscribe` to the `Observable`

Comment: There are some other comments on your post which may contribute to the problem.

Comment: I did the on subscribe like this: this.cabinService.updatePosts(this.cabin.id, this.comment).subscribe(); but I am getting this error: error TS2551: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'. Did you mean 'unsubscribe'? in the command prompt. You can see my stackblitz as well